# How does the Opensocial pageViewer/pageOwner concept work?

Tags: oauth, opensocial

My Problem might be simple, but i just dont know how the `pageViewer/pageOwner` concept work or its better to say i dont know how i can get rid of this system.
I just want to make a *Gadget*, which handles all `Oauth-authentifications` for Networks like *Twitter*, *Google+* etc.

So basicly i want to let the User say how many Networks he wants to access and then i make all `Oauth-authentifications`, i use `Liferay` and `Opensocial` for that task but get this error:

```
OAuth error: UNKNOWN_PROBLEM: Client state belongs to a different person (state owner=G-10180, pageViewer=10196) ==== Original request: GET /m8/feeds/contacts/default/base?alt=json Host: www.google.com X-Shindig-AuthType: oauth X-Forwarded-For: 87.139.78.177 X-shindig-dos: on ====
```

I guess i have to change something in the `shindig.properties` file, but this is where i need your help.

-------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------
I know that the first part of my Authentication works because i get a authentication token, but it is invalid. I assume that the gadget expects a token identical to the token the owner stored.

It would be perfect if you have a little code example for me to identify the viewer as new user if he isnt already a member. Please tell me where i have to put this code in my gadget because the documentation of opensocial costed much lifetime til now, but i cant find an answere to this issue :).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please see my response to your other question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255016/how-to-add-twitter-support-for-opensocial-on-a-apache-tomcat-liferay/8406108#8406108)

You're basically encountering the same problem where the viewer is not the page owner. As I mentioned in your other question, the page viewer must be the page owner for OAuth gadgets (in other words, you must add the OAuth gadget to a page you own).

I'm hoping that a future version of Shindig will fully support adding OAuth gadgets to pages where the viewer != owner, but I'm having difficulty getting feedback from the Shindig community (see [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shindig-dev/201109.mbox/%3CCAJN0zN4_sgDpc3gDmVi98QPgjY6zy7-LSPV-1252rgFu+M7BPg@mail.gmail.com%3E))

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse, but that viewer != owner isnt possible jet is a huge problem. Anyone an idea on that issue?

Comment: Any OpenSocial container using the reference Shindig implementation (which is most containers) will have this restriction unless they've coded around it. If you read my forum post [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shindig-dev/201111.mbox/%3CCAJN0zN4APzvDQHmQAvmDb_gH1TLU6L-pZFqGA5M-13Uens5R_g@mail.gmail.com%3E), it explains the problem in detail. I've got it working where viewer != owner by changing Shindig's source, but I'm not sure what the security implications are.

Comment: It might have something to do with Liferays Virtual Hosts and the Robots.txt look at my console from eclipse, this might help us ;)

11:42:18,864 INFO  [PortalImpl:4701] Current URL /robots.txt generates exception: No VirtualHost exists with the key {hostname=www.portal.*****.de}
11:42:18,864 INFO  [PortalImpl:4722] com.liferay.portal.NoSuchVirtualHostException: No VirtualHost exists with the key {hostname=www.portal.******.de}

Comment: No, the viewer != owner problem is fully due to the Shindig implementation. Please read my forum post linked in the last comment. Again, I know how to fix/workaround the issue, but again, I'm not sure what the security implications are. If you want to try it yourself, you can download the source for Shindig 2.0.2, go to OAuthRequest.checkCanApprove() and remove the condition "!stateOwner.equals(pageViewer)" in line 326. Rebuild Shindig, replace existing Shindig WAR in Liferay's OpenSocial portlet, and rebuild the portlet.

Comment: thanks for the instructions , but if the security of this implementation is unknown, it is a to high risk for clients. I tought Opensocial could help me to get access tokens the simplest way in liferay but know i search for a new one.